# AngularJS reset filter that nothing is filtered

Tags: angularjs, filter

I use a filter at my ng-repeat and it works fine when I navigate to page (everything is shown - nothing is filtered) and when I filter also all is fine.
I only have problems when I will "deselect" the filter in that way that I select < option>< /option> in the select input. Than nothing is shown instead of all.
Does anyone know what I can do that when I select < option>< /option> that all is shown like at the beginning - when I navigate to the page?

```
somethingToIterate | filter: {institutionUserRole: {value: roleFilter}}
```

My select looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control roleSelect" ng-model="roleFilter" ng-options="role as role | translate for role in vm.roles">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an object in ng-model, I think you will need to add the default option to the list you loop thru in the ng-repeat.
Like this:

```
 $scope.options = [
   //add the default value in the options list.
   {'value':'', 'label':''},
   {'value':'1', 'label':'Option 1'},
   {'value':'2', 'label':'Option 2'},
   {'value':'3', 'label':'Option 3'},
   {'value':'4', 'label':'Option 4'},
   {'value':'5', 'label':'Option 5'},
   {'value':'6', 'label':'Option 6'}
 ];


<div class="jumbotron">
  <select ng-model="option" ng-options="item as item.label for item in options track by item.value">
  </select>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter: {name: option.value}">{{item.name}}   
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or you can try it like this,

```
<select ng-model="selected.option">
  <option value='' >select</option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="option.value">{{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Here is a working example.  http://codepen.io/mkl/full/qZjwJG/

Comment: can you verify what roleFilter is set to using  </pre>{{roleFilter}}</pre> somewhere on the page.

Comment: before</pre>{{roleFilter}}</pre>after -> beforeafter, so its an empty string.

Comment: try creating the options with ng-repeat.   <option></option><option ng-repeat="role as role | translate for role in vm.roles" value="{{role}}">{{role}}</option>

Comment: if this solved your issue will you accept the answer.  Thanks